# TSQL 2012 - MERGE - OUTPUT - change data capture - union inserted and deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2012

I have just started playing around with the OUTPUT operator of the MERGE statement and a question popped out immediately:

There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
     id INT
    , somedata VARCHAR(10)
    , someotherdata INT
    );
```

... with some test data in it:

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.t1
VALUES  ( 1, 'aaa', 100 ),
        ( 2, 'bbb', 200 ),
        ( 3, 'ccc', 300 ),
        ( 4, 'ccc', 444 ),
        ( 5, 'rrr', 543 );
```

There is also a change data capture table, as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 0 CONVERT(TINYINT, 0) action -- delete (-1) / update (0) / insert (1)
      , CONVERT(BIGINT, 0) execution_id -- from a sequence, 
                                        -- to distinguish rows
                                        -- for each MERGE operation
      , CONVERT(BIT, 0) row_version -- 0: old, 1: new
      , t2.*
INTO    t1_cdc
FROM    dbo.t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.t1 t2 ON 0 = 1;
```

(the left outer join guarantees nullability of each column in the CDC table)

There is a MERGE statement:

```
;WITH    cte_sample_rows
          AS ( SELECT   1 id
                      , 'aaa' somedata
                      , 100 someotherdata    -- same
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   2
                      , 'bbb'
                      , 200                  -- same
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   3
                      , 'fff'
                      , 333                  -- update
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   4
                      , 'ccc'
                      , 444                  -- same
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   50
                      , 'xxx'
                      , 5050                 -- insert id=50 / delete id=5
               )
    MERGE dbo.t1 tgt
    USING cte_sample_rows src
    ON tgt.id = src.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
               tgt.somedata = src.somedata
             , tgt.someotherdata = src.someotherdata
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT
        VALUES ( src.id
               , src.somedata
               , src.someotherdata
               )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE;
```

Now, I need to capture old and new version of each row, as two separate rows in the CDC table.

I know can add the OUTPUT clause to the above MERGE statement, like this:

```
...
OUTPUT
    CASE $action
      WHEN 'DELETE' THEN -1
      WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN 0
      ELSE 1 -- 'INSERT'
    END AS action
  , 1 AS execution_id
  , Deleted.id id_old
  , Deleted.somedata somedata_old
  , Deleted.someotherdata someotherdata_old
  , Inserted.id id_new
  , Inserted.somedata somedata_new
  , Inserted.someotherdata someotherdata_new ;
```

...but this returns all old and new values as a single row (for each input row). I need to "unpivot" them to get separate rows: one for Inserted and another for Deleted. For deletions there will only be Deleted, for Inserts - only Inserted, and for updates - both (I will distinguish them with version number: 0: old, 1: new)

**I know I can populate an interim #temp table and then "unpivot" the data from that table in a separate step but I am looking for a one-step operation.**

Something like:

```
...
OUTPUT
(SELECT -1 AS action -- DELETE
  , 1 AS execution_id
  , 0 AS row_version -- old
  , Deleted.*
  WHERE $action = 'DELETE'
  UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS action -- UPDATE'
  , 1 AS execution_id
  , 0 AS row_version -- old
  , Deleted.*
  WHERE $action = 'UPDATE'
  UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS action -- UPDATE'
  , 1 AS execution_id
  , 1 AS row_version -- new
  , Inserted.*
  WHERE $action = 'UPDATE'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS action -- INSERT
  , 1 AS execution_id
  , 1 AS row_version -- new
  , Inserted.*
  WHERE $action = 'INSERT')
```

So, once again: one CDC row for each deleted record, one CDC row for each inserted record and two CDC rows for each updated record.

Is there any way of achieving this in a single step?

SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I can populate an interim #temp table and then "unpivot" the data from that table in a separate step **but I am looking for a one-step operation.**

This is very good question. The `MERGE` statement is **Swiss-Army Knife** so I tried this approach:

```
INSERT INTO
SELECT ...
FROM (
     MERGE
     ...
     OUTPUT
     ...
     )
```

There is one problem though, I cannot split row into two because I cannot use `GROUP BY, CROSS JOIN, CROSS APPLY, nested subquery, PIVOT, UNPIVOT, UNION ALL, cte`. Every attempt ends with:

```
 A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement 
 is not allowed as the table source of a PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.

 A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed
 in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows 
 for an INSERT statement.

 A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed
 on either side of a JOIN or APPLY operator.

 The GROUP BY clause is not allowed when the FROM clause contains 
 a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.
```

The closest result set I get is (for `UPDATE` you will get only new/old values at time):

```
;INSERT INTO #cdc(action, execution_id, rowversion,id, somedata, someotherdata)
SELECT 
    [action]
   ,[execution_id]
   ,[rowversion]    = CASE action WHEN -1 THEN 0 
                                  WHEN 1  THEN 1 
                                  WHEN 0  THEN 1
                      END
   ,[id]            = CASE action WHEN -1 THEN id_old 
                                  WHEN 1  THEN id_new 
                                  WHEN 0  THEN id_old
                      END
   ,[somedata]      = CASE action WHEN -1 THEN somedata_old
                                  WHEN 1  THEN somedata_new
                                  WHEN 0  THEN somedata_old
                      END 
   ,[someotherdata] = CASE action WHEN -1 THEN someotherdata_old 
                                  WHEN 1  THEN someotherdata_new
                                  WHEN 0  THEN someotherdata_old
                      END
FROM (
    MERGE #t1 tgt
    USING (VALUES (1, 'aaa', 100),(2, 'bbb', 200),
                  (3, 'fff', 333), (4, 'ccc', 4444),
                  (50, 'xxx', 5050)) AS src(id, somedata, someotherdata)
    ON tgt.id = src.id
    WHEN MATCHED AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT src.somedata, src.someotherdata
                                 INTERSECT
                                 SELECT tgt.somedata, tgt.someotherdata)
    THEN
        UPDATE SET
               tgt.somedata = src.somedata
             , tgt.someotherdata = src.someotherdata
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT
        VALUES ( src.id
               , src.somedata
               , src.someotherdata
               )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE
    OUTPUT
    CASE $action
      WHEN 'DELETE' THEN -1
      WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN 0
      ELSE 1 -- 'INSERT'
    END AS action
  , 1 AS execution_id
  , Inserted.*
  , Deleted.*) 
AS m(action, execution_id, id_new, somedata_new, someotherdata_new
    ,id_old, somedata_old, someotherdata_old);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387730)**</kbd>

Also keep in mind that in current form your `MERGE` will `UPDATE` rows you marked as the same. I added additional condtion to check if at least one column is changed.

```
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT src.somedata, src.someotherdata
                             INTERSECT
                             SELECT tgt.somedata, tgt.someotherdata)
THEN
```

Another approach is to add triggers on target table for `UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE` that will insert records to cdc table and forget about `OUTPUT` clause in `MERGE`.